# On the minimum distance along an orbit

Tags: smooth-manifolds, manifolds, group-actions, isometries

Let $\Gamma$ be a nontrivial group of isometries of $\mathbb{S}^n$, $n \geq 2$, acting properly discontinuously. For $p \in \mathbb{S}^n$, define

$$r(p) = \min_{g \in \Gamma \setminus\{e\} } d(p, g(p)), $$

that is, $r(p)$ is the minimum distance to $p$ of a point in its orbit. As the sphere is a homogeneous manifold, I expect $r$ to be a constant function, although I couldn't prove it. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: If not even $d(p,g(p))$ is independent of $p$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557539/on-the-minimum-distance-along-an-orbit/2557650#2557650